# ¿Se puede usar el mismo button para que realice dos acciones al presionarlo?

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito que un mismo button realice dos acciones, estas acciones son las siguientes:en ambos casos van a guardar unos datos que el usuario ingrese en dos input-text, necesito que se guarden en variables distintas.
Además de esto me gustaría saber si es posible usar una variable que está dentro de una function en otra function porque necesito manipular los resultados que me da una function en otra function. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```js
let n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
let button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let obtenern1 = n1.value;
  let convertir = Number(obtenern1);
  console.log(obtenern1);
});
let contenido = document.getElementById("texto")
let button = document.getElementById("button")
let vector = []

let cambiados = []
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let valor = contenido.value.split(",")

  let nuevoVector = valor.forEach((elemento) => {
    cambiados.push(Number(elemento))

  })
  let ordenado = cambiados.sort((x, y) => {
    return x - y
  })
  let conteo_lista = cambiados.length;

})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1">
<input type="text" id="texto">
<button id="button">Crear el vector</button>
```

Comment: Se puede, pero has intentado definir la variable button dos veces... si comentas la segunda declaración tu código debería funcionar

Comment: La respuesta es *SI*. Saludos

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, ahora quiero saber si es posible usar una variable que esté dentro de una function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te respondo a las preguntas que haces.

> ¿Se puede usar el mismo button para que realice dos acciones al
>   presionarlo?

Si. Declara dos eventos onclick o mejor, declara un único evento onclick que haga las dos cosas que quieres hacer.

> es posible usar una variable que está dentro de una function en otra
>   function

En principio no puedes usar una variable de otra función, salvo que la función que tiene esa variable contega a la función en la que quieras usar dicha variable. Ejemplos:

```
var a;

function fun1(x) {
    var b = 3;
    a = x + b; // OK -> a, x y b están definidos en este ámbito o en algún ámbito superior.
} 

function fun2(x) {
    a = x + b; // NO OK -> La variable b no está definida en este ámbito
}

function fun3() {

    var c;

    function fun4(x) {
       c = x + 2; // OK -> c está definido en la función fun3, pero fun3 contiene a fun4
    }

}
```